# Laravel test unable to find vendor class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm using laravel7 and codeception; and I have an Api test class called `abcCest` located inside `test/api` folder.

it looks like this:

```
<?php

use Tests\TestCase;

class abcCest extends TestCase
{}
```

the parent class `TestCase` has the following content:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error: Trait 'Tests\CreatesApplication' not found in /var/www/tests/TestCase.php on line 7

which is the exact place where i use the trait. The problem is that the trait `CreatesApplication` exists inside the vendor folder under the path: `vendor/laravel/laravel/tests/CreatesApplication.php` and this is its content:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

in my `composer.json` file i have the following already set:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "database/",
      "library/"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
```

i ran composer dump-autoload many times but still keep on getting the same error...

Comment: you have to use `use` in your TestCase file to tell php where is CreatesApplication file

Comment: @GiacomoM if u notice, you will see that the abstract parent `testCase` has the same namespace as the trait itself. I also double checked and found that they r both in the same folder, that's why it's using it without the need to add the `use` statement... but i still tried to use it in my `testCase` class exactly how i used the parent abstract `TestCase` by adding: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\CreatesApplication;` but i still get the same error, in fact even my IDE detects that the class doesnt exist, which is weird as both r literally inside the same folder and share the same namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that the namespace does not match where Composer's autoload thinks it is. According to PSR-4 specs you can't have the same namespace in multiple directories, so the file cannot be autoloaded.

You have two options: manually include the file (I honestly have no idea how this would be done for a trait) or just copy the method out of the trait into your base class.

---

The *real* problem is that you're including this trait at all. It's automatically part of the base Laravel `TestCase` class that you extend. You can already use it by calling `$this->createApplication()` within your test methods.

---

Although thinking further about this, it seems you might be misunderstanding how a Laravel app is set up. The `laravel/laravel` package isn't meant to be included in your app; it *is* your app, or at least the skeleton of what will become your app. So what you're referring to as the `vendor/laravel/laravel/tests` directory should be your app's `tests` directory.

Comment: thank you so much i just took a look at the laravel erpo and found that this trait should be part of my test folder instead of trying to use it from the vendor laravel package.. i spent hours trying to figure this out and i wasn't even open to the fact that this file should exist in my local files.. problem solved now thanks to your answer

Answer (score 0):

There should be a namespace declaration in your test class.
Also you should have the `CreatesApplication.php` file in your app's tests folder.

Comment: my `abcCest` is already able to access the testCase, which can also extend from the abstract `BaseTestCase`.. the problem is that the parent abstract `testCase` isn't able to access the `CreatesApplication` trait which exists in the same folder and under the same namespace.. that's why I'm so confused.